# Avoid color quantization when painting translucent colors in Qt

Tags: qt, transparency, qpainter, qimage, porter-duff

I'd like to use Qt 5.2 to create images with alpha in them, but I'm finding that the color values are being quantized. Here's an example:

```
QColor testColor(248, 64, 16, 2);

QImage image(10, 10, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
painter.fillRect(0, 0, 5, 5, testColor);
painter.end();

qDebug("Test color was (%d, %d, %d, %d)",
       testColor.red(), testColor.green(), testColor.blue(), testColor.alpha());

QRgb value = image.pixel(1, 1);
qDebug("QPainter painted (%d, %d, %d, %d)",
       qRed(value), qGreen(value), qBlue(value), qAlpha(value));
```

This prints out:

```
Test color was (248, 64, 16, 2)
QPainter painted (255, 127, 0, 2)
```

In my application, preserving the original red, green, and blue values is important. Is there a Qt option that I've missed or is this just the expected behavior of the Qt 2D renderer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QPainter` uses the Raster backend by default. It seems that this backend internally operates with *premultiplied* RGBA data. This causes data loss in RGB channels for low alpha. It seems that there is no simple way to change this behavior. You may try to use `OpenGL` or `OpenVG` backends if possible. Backends are described in [this section of the docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qpainter.html#performance). Another option is to implement rendering on `QImage` manually. You also can try to render RGB and alpha channel on 2 different images and somehow join them after that. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614939/pyqt-create-qpixmap-with-alpha-channel-and-not-premultiplied-color-channels).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there's no avoiding the internal premultiplied alpha conversion and back. I ended up rendering to two images and combining them at the end similar to what you suggested.